# Calling an Oracle stored procedure in C# using "Oracle.DataAccess" (with a parameter)

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, oracle10g, ora-06550

So I'm trying to call an Oracle stored procedure from my C# .NET application. Most online references I can find suggest "using System.Data.OracleClient;", but .Net 3.5 doesn't recognize that namespace so I'm using "Oracle.DataAccess.Client" instead.

Here's some paraphrasing of my code below, with a previously setup and tested OracleConnection called 'myConn' already filled with parameter ':arg_myArg' (it's a number, if that matters):

```
command.Connection = myConn;
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = "exec mySchema.myProc(:arg_myArg)"
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The trick is that **the procedure returns nothing by design**, it simply populates a different table which I pull from. However, when I try to run the code above, I get a 'OracleException' on the final line and gives this error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "MYSCHEMA" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "MYSCHEMA" to continue.
```

Removing the "exec" from the command gives this error instead:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
PLS-00801: internal error [22503]
ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

**Any ideas?** I'd be happy to clarify anything

This is my first time posting on stackoverflow.com and my last week at this job, so I appreciate your understanding and relative haste with figuring this out

Comment: I'd urge you to use the Microsoft client.  Make sure you add a reference to System.Data.OracleClient.dll

Comment: why @pilotcam? Microsoft has depreciated the MS Oracle client (System.Data.OracleClient) and recommends using ODP (Oracle.DataAccess.Client).  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/15/system-data-oracleclient-update.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to something like this

```
command.Connection = myConn;
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
command.CommandText = "mySchema.myProc";  // the proc name   
command.Parameters.Add(/* TODO: Add parameter here */); 
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it.

FOR FUTURE INFORMATION SEEKERS:
Turns out to run it, I had to NOT include "exec" in the command, NOT include the parameter in the procedure call, and keep the oracle parameter saved in the **command**, NOT its connection.