# ORA-06550 error calling stored procedure from external service

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

I created a stored procedure in a DB package which does an insert on a table and received the following error from an external service:

```
error: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00801: internal error [22503]     ORA06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

!source: Oracle Data Provider for .NET

I changed the procedure to this for testing:

```
 PROCEDURE P_InsertNewGrade IS

   BEGIN

     NULL

   END P_InsertNewGrade;
```

and I still get the same error message. I am using the following procedure call in the external service:

```
buskgrdc.p_insertnewgrade()
```

The command type option I am using is stored procedure. I can log into sqlplus and execute the procedure without errors.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Check out this --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378683/calling-an-oracle-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp-using-oracle-dataaccess-with-a

Comment: Please show all relevant Client code.  Also, I am assuming the above PL/SQL code is not what you actually compiled, as you are missing a semi-colon,